# Problems while controling the margin of an HTML text area?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to slightly move to the right the text area, and close the vertical gap between the text area and the title in this html element:

```html
<crowd-form answer-format="flatten-objects">


<script src="https://assets.crowd.aws/crowd-html-elements.js"></script>

<div>
      <h4>Write an essay</h4>
      <crowd-text-area name="essay"rows="2" placeholder="Write here ...."></crowd-text-area>
    </div>
    
    
</crowd-form>
```

So far I tried to locally control the margins of the above element like this:

```
style= "margin-left:50px"
```

However, although this is moving the textbox horizontally, vertically it is not reducing the gap between the title and te text area. Something like this:

[image]

How can I reduce the gap and move the textarea to the right at the same time locally, to avoid wrecking other styling that I have in my document?

I also tried to:

`div style='margin-left:150px;margin-top: 1px;'>`

However, I am unable to control the vertical margin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the margin on the heading element:

```
h4 {margin-bottom: 0;}
```

Then, put some padding on a containing element:

```
.pad-left {padding-left: 50px;}
```

```html
<style>
    h4 {margin-bottom: 0;}
    .pad-left {padding-left: 50px;}
</style>

<crowd-form answer-format="flatten-objects">
    <script src="https://assets.crowd.aws/crowd-html-elements.js"></script>
    
    <div>
        <h4>Write an essay</h4>
    
        <div class="pad-left">
           <crowd-text-area name="essay"rows="2" placeholder="Write here ...."></crowd-text-area>
        </div>
    </div>
</crowd-form>
```

Answer (score 1):

On the H4 tag it has margin-bottom already on 21px so you can set it to 0 to get them closer.

```
<h4 style="margin-bottom: 0px;">Write an essay</h4>
```

You can add padding to your textarea div to move it more to the right.

```
<div class="textarea-container fit" style="padding-left: 10px;">
      <textarea id="textarea" rows="2" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Write here ...." aria-labelledby="paper-input-label-1"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Inline styles are ick. At least use an embedded style tag.